# How to use python inside of shellscript to run a powershell command?

Tags: python, powershell, shell, zos

Could anyone please assist me in accomplishing this? I'm trying to figure out if I can run this zowe cli command inside a python file which is inside a shell script file.

```
zowe zos-files list all-members "ZZZZ.XXX" -a
```

For example my shell script and python file look like this

```
shell_script_file.sh

python3 python_file.py

-----------

python_file.py

import subprocess
subprocess.run(.....)
```

When I run the shell script file, it prompts me for my hostname, userid, and password. However, it is not asked when I run the zowe command in the pwsh terminal. I'm trying to get the same result in the pwsh terminal using Python code.

*One more thing, please..*
I'm doing this because I need to look up the user of a Dataset member. Is there another way to find it in Python (like, without using subprocess)? I also use the zoautil_py module.

Comment: Review this MS article: [PowerShell- Running Executables - TechNet Articles - United States (English) - TechNet Wiki](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)